# Performance and diagnostics with "Cannot start service... A Windows Service must first be intalled (using installutil.exe)..."

Tags: c#, windows, performance, service, diagnostics

Presently, I am attempting to profile a Windows service that I am working on using the new "Performance and Diagnostics" feature in Visual Studio 2013 (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/07/12/performance-and-diagnostics-hub-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx).  When I attempt to profile the service, I get this error message:

```
Cannot start service from the command line or a debugger.  A Windows Service must first be intalled (using installutil.exe) and then started with the ServerExplorer, Windows Services Administrative Tool or the NET START command.
```

Normally when debugging the service, it works fine because I have the following code in Program.cs:

```
    private static MySvc _serviceInstance;
    private static readonly List<ServiceBase> _servicesToRun =
        new List<ServiceBase>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _servicesToRun.Add(_serviceInstance);

        if (Environment.UserInteractive)
        {
            _servicesToRun.ToArray().LoadServices();
        }
        else
        {
            ServiceBase.Run(_servicesToRun.ToArray());
        }
    }

    static Program()
    {
        _serviceInstance = new MySvc();
    }
```

Also, if I attempt to attach to a running app, in the dialog that appears it doesn't display any executing processes, and when I put the name of the service in there, it does not find it.  Does anyone have any suggestions?  TIA.

**UPDATE:** This is what I get when I attempt to attach to a process.  Why doesn't the "Performance and Diagnostics" see any processes running on my computer?  Why would it only connect to Windows Store apps instead of all exes?  Please see this image:

[image]

Comment: try to attach to the service process with VS performance tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I resolved the problem was the copy all the source code and make minor modifications to get everything to run in a Console application, then chose Debug->Performance and Diagnostics and ran the Console application using "Change Target" ->  "Launch and executable file (.exe)"